# TypeErro: cannot read property 'create' of undefined

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, next.js

I get this error whenever i try to register a user from the register form.
I've tried the solution i got here ["TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62562791/typeerror-cannot-read-property-create-of-undefined).
Here's my index.js from models directory

```
    const fs = require("fs");
    const path = require("path");
    const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
    const basename = path.basename(__filename);
    const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development";
    const config = require(__dirname + "/../config.js")[env];
    const db = {};
    
    let sequelize;
    if (config.use_env_variable) {
      sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
    } else {
      sequelize = new Sequelize(
        config.database,
        config.username,
        config.password,
        config
      );
    }
    
    fs.readdirSync(__dirname)
      .filter((file) => {
        return (
          file.indexOf(".") !== 0 && file !== basename && file.slice(-3) === ".js"
        );
      })
      .forEach((file) => {
        const model = sequelize['import'](path.join(__dirname, file));
        db[model.name] = model;
      });
    
    Object.keys(db).forEach((modelName) => {
      if (db[modelName].associate) {
        db[modelName].associate(db);
      }
    });
    
    db.sequelize = sequelize;
    db.Sequelize = Sequelize;
    
    module.exports = db;
```

**here's my user.js from the models**

```
    const { Model } = require("sequelize");
    module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
      class User extends Model {
        /**
              msg:
         * Helper method for defining associations.
         * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
         * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
         */
        static associate(models) {
          // define association here
        }
      }
      User.init(
        {
          firstName: DataTypes.STRING,
          lastName: DataTypes.STRING,
          email: DataTypes.STRING,
          userRole: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            validate: {
              isIn: {
                args: [["Enrollment Officer", "Supervisor", "Support Officer"]],
              },
            },
          },
        },
        {
          sequelize,
          modelName: "Users",
        }
      );
      return User;
    };
```

and here's my userService.js file

```
    import database from "@models/index";

    const { User } = database;
    
    export default class UserService {
      static async createUser(user) {
        try {
          const newUser = await User.create(user);
          return newUser;
        } catch (error) {
          throw error;
        }
      }
    }
```

The error points to the **.create** property attached to the User in my userService file.

Comment: Have you checked the `const { User } = database;` User value in the file? It seems you are unable to get it at first place.

Comment: error happens in `const newUser = await User.create(user);` where and how did you call UserService.createUser ?

Comment: ``` import database from "@models/index";

const { User } = database;

export default class UserService {
  static async createUser(user) {
    try {
      const newUser = await User.create(user);
      return newUser;
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i called the newUser in my userService file which is in my services folder

Comment: Reza, here's the code `import database from "@models/index";

const { User } = database;

export default class UserService {
  static async createUser(user) {
    try {
      const newUser = await User.create(user);
      return newUser;
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }
}
`

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara how do I check that

Comment: Console log the value of the `User` object like this: `console.log(User);` and post the results.

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara. I did that and it gave the the user object inputed in the register form

Comment: Have you tried replacing `__dirname` with `process.cwd()`? There are some known issues with using `__dirname` in Next.js.

Comment: Yes, I did. but still thesame error.

Comment: @Reza i called the User.create(user) in my api/register.js file. Here's how i did that... `import UserService from "@services/userService";

export default async function register(req, res) {
  if (req.method === "POST") {
    const data = req.body;
    const response = await UserService.createUser(data);
    console.log("data: ", response);
  } else {
    res.status(400).json({
      message: "Method is not allowed",
    });
  }
}`

Comment: add a console log after `const data = req.body;` to watch data, for sure data is null

Comment: @Reza It returned an object with the information inputed in the register form

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara... any ideas on how to modify importing the other files in the models folder into the index file. I believe that's where the error is. Your inputs are highly appreciated

Comment: @Reza ... any ideas on how to modify importing the other files in the models folder into the index file. I believe that's where the error is. Your inputs are highly appreciated

Comment: @Anatoly please do you have any solution for me? It's very crucial